# Bind ng-model in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to bind $index onto an ng-model so that when I send it back to controller, I can console.log its value.

I chose to use ngForm because I read that in order for data to bind on dynamic form creation, there should be subforms so that the outer `<form>` can validate. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Inside the section, I have a button that shows information about the spot (current people, max occupation, and percent full). That seems to be working fine with the $index setting and checking (though I'm not sure if that is affecting $index, which might affect the form's $index).

My output when I call console.log($scope.asdf) = Object {location: 10}, but the desired output is "Object {location: [from 0-11 since I have 11 items in the places array]}.

In HTML:

```
<div id="page-wrapper" ng-show="loggedin" ng-controller="StudySpaces">
<form location="locationForm" ng-submit="submitLocation()" novalidate>
    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="content" ng-repeat="(i, place) in places track by $index | limitTo: 8:0">
        <section>
            ...
            <a class="button small" ng-click="selectClicked($index)" style="margin-bottom:20px; padding: 0px 20px;">View/Report Space</a>
            <!-- To report how many people there -->

            <section class="row" ng-show="isClicked($index)" style="margin-bottom:15px;">

                <div class="4u 12u(narrower)">
                    <section>
                        <header>
                            <h3>Current people</h3>
                            {{ place[1] }} people
                        </header>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="4u 12u(narrower)">
                    <section>
                        <header>
                            <h3>Max Occupancy</h3>
                            {{ place[2] }} people
                        </header>
                    </section>
                </div>
                ...

                <ng-form>
                    <input type="text" name="asdf.location" ng-model="asdf.location" ng-init="asdf.location = $index" style="display:none;">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">I'm studying in {{place[0]}}!</button>
                </ng-form>
            </section> <!-- End of .row -->

         </section>
     </div> <!--End of .content, ngRepeat -->
</form>
</div>
```

In controller:
app.controller('StudySpaces', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {

```
$scope.places = {};
$scope.tabClicked = 0;

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'cgi-bin/populateplaces.py'
}).then(function(data) {
    // 0 = name, 1 = current ppl, 2 = max, 3 = percent, 4 = preview, 5 = description, 6 = image
    $scope.places = data.data;
    console.log($scope.places);

}); //End of $http

$scope.selectClicked = function(number) {
    $scope.tabClicked = number;
}

$scope.isClicked = function(checkTab) {
    return $scope.tabClicked === checkTab;
}

$scope.asdf = {};

$scope.submitLocation = function() {
    console.log($scope.asdf);
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure but you might want to track not by `$index` but by the provided  `i` in the tuple `(i, place)`?

Comment: Initialize `asdf.location` to an empty array in your controller. Change to `ng-model="asdf.location[$index]"` and `ng-init="asdf.location[$index] = $index"`. That's what you want, right? Please simplify your question if you want some answers. As you can see, the way I suggested doesn't make much sense.

Comment: This isn't an appropriate place for `ng-init`, and the logic used here won't do what you expect.  Right now, you have a single `$scope.asdf` object, and for each `place`, you are calling `ng-init`, where you are updating the `asdf.location` property with the index of that `place`. Each `place` that is iterated will replace the value already there, meaning that you will always end up with `location` equal to the last value.